# Make lists of certain length using multiple other lists

Tags: notepad++, database, notepad, duplicate, list

I have a lot of relatively small files with about 350.000 lines of text.
For example:

File 1:

```
 1. asdf
 2. wetwert
 3. ddghr
 4. vbnd
 ...
 264187. sdfre
```

File 2:

```
 1. erye
 2. yren
 3. asdf
 4. jkdt
 ...
 184168. uory
```

As you can see line 3 of file 2 is a duplicate of line 1 in file 1.
I want a program / Notepad++ Plugin that can check and remove these duplicates in multiple files.

The next problem I have is that I want all lists to be combined into large 1.000.000 line files.
So, for example, I have these files:

- 648563 lines
- 375924 lines
- 487036 lines

I want them to result in these files:

- 1.000.000 lines
- 511.523 lines

And the last 2 files must consist of only unique lines.
How can I possibly do this? Can I use some programs for this? Or a combination of multiple Notepad++ Plugins?
I know GSplit can split files of 1.536.243 into files of 1.000.000 and 536.243 lines, but that is not enough, and it doesn't remove duplicates.

I do want to create my own Notepad++ plugin or program if needed, but I have no idea how and where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Excel to do that, just copy the text of all your text files into an excel column, then use delete duplicate in Excel.

Comment: @Yacine I think that is practically impossible because there are more and more files added over time, and I currently have about 10Million lines. And if I were to do it that way, how can I export everything in files of 1 million lines?

Comment: This seems a natural for command-line utilities. In Linux you would use: `cat "File "* | sort | uniq | split -d -l 1000000 - Combined.`; this would generate `Combined.00`, `Combined.01`, ... There are Windows versions of all these utilities, though the run strings may differ slightly.

Comment: @AFH Your solution works pretty well, except for the 'split' part. I can not find a Windows equivalent for that. Do you have an idea how I could solve that? Because the combining, sorting, removing duplicates and saving to a new file works very well.

Comment: Among other places, it is included with the utilities in [win-bash](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/).

Comment: nonono :) not win-bash. This is 2017. Use PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a script for Windows Powershell and saved it as a .ps1 file. I created it as the following:

```
$linecount = 0 
$editfilenumber = 1
$endfilenumber = 1
$totallines = 0
$i = 0
$interval = 100 / 1
```

This part is just for resetting all the basic variables.
`$linecount` is used for the number of lines created in the new parts (talk about that later). `$editfilenumber` is used for the file number that is being edited (Duplicates removed, invalids removed...). `$endfilenumber` is used for the part number that has been created. `$totallines` is used for the total number of lines. `$i` is used for calculating the percentages. `$interval` is used for the refresh interval of the progress bar (otherwise the process would be very slow)

```
$srcdirectory = Read-host "Select path to the source folder"
$partdirectory = Read-host "Select path to where the parts need to be stored"
$maxlines = Read-host "How many lines are in the new parts?"
$maxsize = [int]$maxlines
$partname = Read-host "How do you want the new parts to be called?"
```

This basically asks the user for the data, and for the number of lines in the parts.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $srcdirectory -filter *.txt
Write-Host "These files will be edited and combined: "
$files | format-table name
```

This will list all the .txt files in the given directory. This is done to let the user know wich files will be used.

```
Write-Host "Press any key to continue..." -foregroundcolor "green"
$HOST.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") | OUT-NULL
$HOST.UI.RawUI.Flushinputbuffer()
```

This waits for user confirmation, by waiting for a key to be pressed.

```
$start = Get-Date
```

This gets the current timestamp to calculate the processing time in the end.

```
ForEach ($file in $files) { 

    Write-host "Editing file: " $file
    Write-host "Loading list..."
    $list = Get-content $srcdirectory\$file
    Write-host "OK" -foregroundcolor "green"

    Write-host "Removing duplicates..."
    $list = $list | Get-Unique
    Write-host "OK" -foregroundcolor "green"

    Write-host "Removing invalid..."
    $list = $list | Where { $_ -notmatch "^@" } | Where { $_ -match "@" }
    $list = $list -replace ';', ':' | Where {$_ -notmatch ':[^\)]+:'} | Where {$_ -notmatch '::'}
    Write-host "OK" -foregroundcolor "green"

    Write-host "Combining lists..."
    $longlist = $longlist + $list | Get-Unique
    $editfilenumber ++
    Write-host "Success!" -foregroundcolor "green"
}
```

This part is quite important. First, it displays what file is being edited, and creates a `$list` of the content of that file. After that, it gets all the unique lines (and thus removing duplicates), remove invalid lines (need to be specified for the purpose of the program) and finally adds the filtered `$list` to  `$longlist`. This is done for each file, and thus each filtered file is added to `$longlist`.

```
Write-Host "Removing all duplicates..."
$longlist = $longlist | Get-Unique
Write-Host "Success!" -foregroundcolor "green"
```

This removes all the duplicates from `$longlist`.

```
Write-host "Calculating total number of lines..."
$longlist | % { $totallines += $_.count }
Write-host "There are a total of " $totallines " unique and valid lines." -
foregroundcolor "green"
```

This calculates the total number of unique valid lines. This is for the user's information and used to calculate the progress in the progress bar.

```
Write-host "Creating parts..."
$longlist | ForEach { 
    Add-Content $partdirectory/$partname.$endfilenumber.txt "$_"  
    $linecount++
    $i++
    If ($linecount -eq $maxsize) { 
        Write-host "Success! " $partname$endfilenumber " created" -foregroundcolor "green"
        $endfilenumber++ 
        $linecount = 0 
    } 
    If ($i % $interval -eq 0) {
        $percent = ($i / $totallines) * 100
        $percent = [math]::Round($percent,2)
        Write-Progress -Activity "Creating parts" -Status $percent -PercentComplete $percent
    }
}
```

This is the most important part. It creates a file with the specified filename in the specified directory. It adds 1 line of $longlist to that file. Then it increases `$linecount` and `$i` with 1. If `$linecount` then equals the specified maximum file size, it increases `$endfilecount` by 1. If not, the next line will be added to the existing file.

For example, The specified filesize is 10.000 lines, and the part name is `Part$endfilenumber`. The first line of `$longlist` is added to file Part1.txt (`$endfilenumber = 1`, as specified in the first lines of code). When the 10.00th line is added, the `If` statement is used. This means that `$endfilenumber` is increased by 1. This way the next line from `$longlist` will be added to a new file called Part2.txt (because `$endfilenumber = 2`).

The second if statement is used for calculating the progress. This isn't very important, so to save time I won't explain that.

```
$end = Get-Date
$time = ($end-$start).TotalMinutes
$time = [math]::Round($time,2)

Write-host "A total of " $endfilenumber " parts have been created" -
foregroundcolor "green"
Write-host "Total processing time: " $time " minutes" -foregroundcolor "green"


Write-Host "Press any key to exit..." -foregroundcolor "green"
$HOST.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") | OUT-NULL
$HOST.UI.RawUI.Flushinputbuffer()
```

This is the last part of code. This takes the timestamp and subtracts it from the timestamp in the beginning. this way the processing time is calculated in minutes and rounded to 2 decimals. The very last bit just waits for user confirmation to end and close the program.

I hoped this helps a bit.

NOTE: This program does NOT affect the original files! So that's nice, I guess...

Comment: In practice your answers arn't just to help you - its the next person with the same issue - so posting your powershell script would be appreciated to avoid the [denvercoder/xkcd 979 effect](https://xkcd.com/979/)